# errors in the photos application in the latest OS distribution

Tags: applications, photos

when will there be an update to the photo app that will stop it from crashing all the time?
the application hangs when importing photos from the images directory

---

and could I ask for info how to do it? I am a novice user

Comment: Try to run it from terminal and get the exect error then it crashes in output.

Comment: a friend uses the Freya version and there is no problem with importing photos from the directory :-(